# Unzip file content hosted in s3 to multiple cloudfront url through a single lambda function

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is there any specific way to unzip single file contents from s3 to multiple cloudfront urls by triggering lambda once.

Lets say in there is a zip file contains multiple jpg/ png files already uploaded to s3. Intention is to run lambda function only once to unzip all its file content and make them available in multiple cloudfront urls.

in s3 bucket

```
archive.zip
   a.jpg
   b.jpg
   c.jpg
```

through cloudfront

```
https://1232.cloudfront.net/a.jpg
https://1232.cloudfront.net/b.jpg
https://1232.cloudfront.net/c.jpg
```

I am looking for a solution such that lambda function trigger function calls whenever a s3 upload happens and make all files available in the zip through cloudfront multiple urls.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Prathap Parameswar,

I think you can resolve your problem like this:

- First you need to exact your zip file
- Seconds you upload them again to S3.

This is lambda python function:

```
import json
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import zipfile

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    source_bucket = 'upload-zip-folder'
    target_bucket = 'upload-extracted-folder'

    my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(source_bucket)

    for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
        if(str(file.key).endswith('.zip')):
            zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=source_bucket, key=file.key)
            buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
            
            z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
            for filename in z.namelist():
                file_info = z.getinfo(filename)
                try:
                    response = s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
                        z.open(filename),
                        Bucket=target_bucket,
                        Key=f'{filename}'
                    )
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
        else:
            print(file.key+ ' is not a zip file.')
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: Thank you for providing your inputs. I am looking for a different solution other than the common approach. Like saving a single object in s3 inorder to avoid multiple put request. My goal is to reduce file entries in s3 and make extracted content available through cloudfront by avoiding roundtrip from s3 to cloudfront.